# Problem is infeasible with Gurobi, feasible with cbc (but can't access objective value)

Tags: python, pyomo, gurobi, coin-or-cbc

I am solving a MILP with cbc and gurobi (via pyomo). Gurobi states that the model is infeasible. As to cbc the solver status states that a feasible and optimal solution is found, but then it fails to access the value of the objective (which in turn crashed my program).

Here is how I access the objective value

```
solver_parameters = "ResultFile=model.lp"
opt = SolverFactory(solver)
        
results = opt.solve(self.model, tee=False, options_string=solver_parameters,logfile="model.log")
# checking status and terminiation condition
print ("The solver returned a status of: "+str(results.solver.status))
print (str(results.solver))
if (results.solver.status == SolverStatus.ok) and (results.solver.termination_condition== TerminationCondition.optimal):
   print ("Problem is feasible and solution is optimal")
        objective_value = value(self.model.objective)
else:
   print("Problem is infeasible")
   objective_value = None
```

With cbc I get

```
The solver returned a status of: ok

- Status: ok
  Message: CBC 2.10.5
  Termination condition: optimal
  Id: 0
  Error rc: 0
  Time: 0.011972904205322266

Problem is feasible and solution is optimal

ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: x[0]
        (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.var._GeneralVarData'>)
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object x[0]
ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: objective
        (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.objective.SimpleObjective'>)
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object x[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "c:...", line 531, in solve
    objective_value = value(self.model.objective)
  File "pyomo\core\expr\numvalue.pyx", line 246, in pyomo.core.expr.numvalue.value
  File "pyomo\core\expr\numvalue.pyx", line 231, in pyomo.core.expr.numvalue.value
  File "C:...\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\expression.py", line 55, in __call__
    return self.expr(exception=exception)
  File "pyomo\core\expr\numeric_expr.pyx", line 218, in pyomo.core.expr.numeric_expr.ExpressionBase.__call__
  File "C:...\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\expr\visitor.py", line 1054, in evaluate_expression
    return visitor.dfs_postorder_stack(exp)
  File "C:...\venv\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\expr\visitor.py", line 584, in dfs_postorder_stack
    flag, value = self.visiting_potential_leaf(_sub)
  File "C:...\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\expr\visitor.py", line 962, in visiting_potential_leaf
    return True, value(node)
  File "pyomo\core\expr\numvalue.pyx", line 246, in pyomo.core.expr.numvalue.value
  File "pyomo\core\expr\numvalue.pyx", line 233, in pyomo.core.expr.numvalue.value
ValueError: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object x[0]
```

On the other hand with gurobi I get

```
WARNING: Loading a SolverResults object with a warning status into
    model.name="unknown";
      - termination condition: infeasible
      - message from solver: Model was proven to be infeasible.
The solver returned a status of: warning

- Status: warning
  Return code: 0
  Message: Model was proven to be infeasible.
  Termination condition: infeasible
  Termination message: Model was proven to be infeasible.
  Wall time: 0.0019626617431640625
  Error rc: 0
  Time: 0.08476400375366211

Problem is infeasible
```

I'm assuming problem is indeed infeasible and the error comes from cbc. Is this kind of error common, and what would be a way to avoid this?

Finally, this is the lp model returned by gurobi

```
\ Model x79
\ LP format - for model browsing. Use MPS format to capture full model detail.
Maximize
  - 100 x12 - 200 x13 - 300 x14 - 400 x15 - 70 x16 - 140 x17 - 90 x18
   - 90 x19
Subject To
 c_u_x80_: x12 - 100 x1 <= 0
 c_u_x81_: x13 - 100 x2 <= 0
 c_u_x82_: x14 - 100 x3 <= 0
 c_u_x83_: x15 - 100 x4 <= 0
 c_u_x84_: x16 - 50 x5 <= 0
 c_u_x85_: x17 - 50 x6 <= 0
 c_u_x86_: x18 - 25 x7 <= 0
 c_u_x87_: x19 - 25 x8 <= 0
 c_l_x88_: x12 >= 0
 c_l_x89_: x13 >= 0
 c_l_x90_: x14 >= 0
 c_l_x91_: x15 >= 0
 c_l_x92_: x16 >= 0
 c_l_x93_: x17 >= 0
 c_l_x94_: x18 >= 0
 c_l_x95_: x19 >= 0
 c_u_x96_: x1 <= 1
 c_u_x97_: x2 <= 1
 c_u_x98_: x3 <= 1
 c_u_x99_: x4 <= 1
 c_u_x100_: x5 <= 1
 c_u_x101_: x6 <= 1
 c_u_x102_: x7 <= 1
 c_u_x103_: x8 <= 1
 c_e_x104_: x12 + x16 = 51
 c_e_x105_: x13 + x17 = 51
 c_e_x106_: x14 + x18 = 51
 c_e_x107_: x15 + x19 = 51
 c_u_x108_: - x7 + x9 <= 0
 c_u_x109_: - x6 + x10 <= 0
 c_u_x110_: - x2 - x3 + x11 <= 0
 c_u_x111_: x7 - 2 x9 <= 0
 c_u_x112_: x6 - 2 x10 <= 0
 c_u_x113_: x2 + x3 - 2 x11 <= 0
 c_u_x114_: 100 x13 + 20 x14 + 100 x17 + 20 x18 <= 6072
 c_u_x115_: - 20 x18 + 1260 x9 <= 0
 c_u_x116_: - 100 x17 + 1260 x10 <= 0
 c_u_x117_: - 100 x13 - 20 x14 + 1260 x11 <= 0
 c_u_x118_: 2 x1 - x24 <= 0
 c_u_x119_: 2 x2 - x25 <= 0
 c_u_x120_: 15 x3 - x26 <= 0
 c_u_x121_: 10 x4 - x27 <= 0
 c_u_x122_: 1.4 x5 - x24 <= 0
 c_u_x123_: 1.4 x6 - x25 <= 0
 c_u_x124_: 4.5 x7 - x26 <= 0
 c_u_x125_: 2.25 x8 - x27 <= 0
 c_u_x126_: 100 x12 + 200 x13 + 300 x14 + 400 x15 + 70 x16 + 140 x17
   + 90 x18 + 90 x19 - 2550 x24 - 5100 x25 - 1020 x26 - 2040 x27 + 6072 x48
   + 100 x60 + 100 x61 + 100 x62 + 100 x63 + 50 x64 + 50 x65 + 25 x66
   + 25 x67 - 1260 x76 - 1260 x77 - 1260 x78 <= 0
 c_u_x127_: - 1000 x1 + x60 <= 0
 c_u_x128_: - 1000 x2 + x61 <= 0
 c_u_x129_: - 1000 x3 + x62 <= 0
 c_u_x130_: - 1000 x4 + x63 <= 0
 c_u_x131_: - 1000 x5 + x64 <= 0
 c_u_x132_: - 1000 x6 + x65 <= 0
 c_u_x133_: - 1000 x7 + x66 <= 0
 c_u_x134_: - 1000 x8 + x67 <= 0
 c_u_x135_: x60 - x32 <= 0
 c_u_x136_: x61 - x33 <= 0
 c_u_x137_: x62 - x34 <= 0
 c_u_x138_: x63 - x35 <= 0
 c_u_x139_: x64 - x36 <= 0
 c_u_x140_: x65 - x37 <= 0
 c_u_x141_: x66 - x38 <= 0
 c_u_x142_: x67 - x39 <= 0
 c_u_x143_: 1000 x1 - x60 + x32 <= 1000
 c_u_x144_: 1000 x2 - x61 + x33 <= 1000
 c_u_x145_: 1000 x3 - x62 + x34 <= 1000
 c_u_x146_: 1000 x4 - x63 + x35 <= 1000
 c_u_x147_: 1000 x5 - x64 + x36 <= 1000
 c_u_x148_: 1000 x6 - x65 + x37 <= 1000
 c_u_x149_: 1000 x7 - x66 + x38 <= 1000
 c_u_x150_: 1000 x8 - x67 + x39 <= 1000
 c_u_x151_: - 1000 x1 + x68 <= 0
 c_u_x152_: - 1000 x2 + x69 <= 0
 c_u_x153_: - 1000 x3 + x70 <= 0
 c_u_x154_: - 1000 x4 + x71 <= 0
 c_u_x155_: - 1000 x5 + x72 <= 0
 c_u_x156_: - 1000 x6 + x73 <= 0
 c_u_x157_: - 1000 x7 + x74 <= 0
 c_u_x158_: - 1000 x8 + x75 <= 0
 c_u_x159_: x68 - x40 <= 0
 c_u_x160_: x69 - x41 <= 0
 c_u_x161_: x70 - x42 <= 0
 c_u_x162_: x71 - x43 <= 0
 c_u_x163_: x72 - x44 <= 0
 c_u_x164_: x73 - x45 <= 0
 c_u_x165_: x74 - x46 <= 0
 c_u_x166_: x75 - x47 <= 0
 c_u_x167_: 1000 x1 - x68 + x40 <= 1000
 c_u_x168_: 1000 x2 - x69 + x41 <= 1000
 c_u_x169_: 1000 x3 - x70 + x42 <= 1000
 c_u_x170_: 1000 x4 - x71 + x43 <= 1000
 c_u_x171_: 1000 x5 - x72 + x44 <= 1000
 c_u_x172_: 1000 x6 - x73 + x45 <= 1000
 c_u_x173_: 1000 x7 - x74 + x46 <= 1000
 c_u_x174_: 1000 x8 - x75 + x47 <= 1000
 c_u_x175_: - 1000 x9 + x76 <= 0
 c_u_x176_: - 1000 x10 + x77 <= 0
 c_u_x177_: - 1000 x11 + x78 <= 0
 c_u_x178_: x76 - x49 <= 0
 c_u_x179_: x77 - x50 <= 0
 c_u_x180_: x78 - x51 <= 0
 c_u_x181_: 1000 x9 - x76 + x49 <= 1000
 c_u_x182_: 1000 x10 - x77 + x50 <= 1000
 c_u_x183_: 1000 x11 - x78 + x51 <= 1000
 c_l_x184_: - 50 x24 + x32 - x40 >= -100
 c_l_x185_: - 100 x25 + 100 x48 + x33 - x41 - 100 x51 >= -200
 c_l_x186_: - 20 x26 + 20 x48 + x34 - x42 - 20 x51 >= -300
 c_l_x187_: - 40 x27 + x35 - x43 >= -400
 c_l_x188_: - 50 x24 + x36 - x44 >= -70
 c_l_x189_: - 100 x25 + 100 x48 + x37 - x45 - 100 x50 >= -140
 c_l_x190_: - 20 x26 + 20 x48 + x38 - x46 - 20 x49 >= -90
 c_l_x191_: - 40 x27 + x39 - x47 >= -90
 c_u_x192_: x24 <= 2
 c_u_x193_: x25 <= 2
 c_u_x194_: x26 <= 15
 c_u_x195_: x27 <= 10
 c_e_ONE_VAR_CONSTANT: ONE_VAR_CONSTANT = 1
Bounds
 x24 free
 x25 free
 x26 free
 x27 free
Binaries
 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10 x11
End
```

Answer (score 1):

This is already answered in this [duplicate question over on OR exchange](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7810/problem-is-infeasible-with-gurobi-feasible-with-cbc-but-cant-access-objective): The problem is indeed infeasible and CBC reports an incorrect optimality status.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the model through IIS, which will show what constraints cause the infeasibilities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed gurobi returns an IIS, but I don't really see how it helps with regard to my initial question. To me the problem is more that cbc says "feasible and optimal" but then can't evaluate the objective function (while gurobi says infeasible).